# CruiseControl 1.6 issue on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to run CruiseControl.Net 1.6.7981.1 on a windows server 2008.  The server and dashboard .config's has been configured.  Visual Studio 2010 is installed on the server
When I start the ccnet service I get the following error:

> CruiseControl.NET Server 1.6.7981.1 -- .NET Continuous Integration
>   Server log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Unhandled exception in
>   GetInfoForAssemb ly System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Core, V ersion=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Core,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c 561934e089'
>   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle*
>   typeIn stArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInst Count)    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[]  typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[]
>   methodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.Module.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[]
>   genericTy peArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttrib
>   uteRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly&
>   lastAptcaOkAssembly, Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken
>   decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes,
>   Runtime Type& attributeType, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean&
>   ctorHasParameters, Bool ean& isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module
>   decoratedModu le, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterTyp e, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly
>   assembly, R untimeType caType)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType,  Boolean inherit)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetInfoForAssembly(Assembly
>   assembl y, String& repositoryName, Type& repositoryType)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
>   icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo gging. To
>   turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus ion!EnableLog].
>
> log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Failed to configure
>   repository [log4net
>   -default-repository] from assembly attributes. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Core, V ersion=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Core,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c 561934e089'
>   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle*
>   typeIn stArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInst Count)    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[]  typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[]
>   methodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.Module.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[]
>   genericTy peArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttrib
>   uteRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly&
>   lastAptcaOkAssembly, Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken
>   decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes,
>   Runtime Type& attributeType, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean&
>   ctorHasParameters, Bool ean& isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module
>   decoratedModu le, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterTyp e, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly
>   assembly, R untimeType caType)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType,  Boolean inherit)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.LoadAliases(Assembly assembly,
>   ILog gerRepository repository)    at
>   log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly
>   repositor yAssembly, Type repositoryType, String repositoryName,
>   Boolean readAssemblyAttri butes)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
>   icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo gging. To
>   turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus ion!EnableLog].
>
> An unexpected error has caused the console to crash, please press any
>   key to con tinue...

Please assist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message says it can't load System.Core of .NET 3.5. Check that it is installed correctly. You could use [this tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) to verify installation, for example.

Comment: With it being a 64 bit OS, might cruisecontol be using the Framework64, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64) where no .NET 3.5 exist?

Comment: Thx for the tool, really helpful. It did confirm that no .NET 3.5 installation existed